# Spring performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

Is there any improved way to JPA these, and how these MVC architecture would fit in API rest? I'd like to understand the difference about it, like how could I turn it into an API rest?

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/autor")
public class AutorController {
    @Autowired
    private AutorRepository autorRepository;
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView all(){

       ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("lista-autor");
       view.addObject("autores",autorRepository.findAll());
       return view;

    }


    @GetMapping("/novo")
    public ModelAndView newAutor(){
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("form-autor");
        view.addObject("autor", new Autor());
        return view;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String  create(Autor novoAutor){
        autorRepository.save(novoAutor);
        return "redirect:/autor";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        autorRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/autor";
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ES_AUTOR")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Autor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private Integer anoNascimento;


}
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface AutorRepository extends JpaRepository<Autor, Long> {
}
```

understand the difference between MVC and API rest.